# ¿Cómo utilizo la etiqueta {% static junto a {{request.?

Tags: python, django

En el campo avatar de mi usuario está guardado el nombre del avatar junto con la extensión, esto es:

avatar = "image.png"

En mi **html** quiero hacer que cargue la imagen desde la carpeta static:

```
src="{% static 'img/avatars/{{request.user.avatar}}' %}">
```

dentro de la carpeta static/img/avatar/ se encuentra la imagen.

Mi problema es que la variable {{request.user.avatar}} no se sustituye por el valor, si no que se escribe tal cual:

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{request.user.avatar}}' from ''img/avatars/'{{request.user.avatar}}'

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo que busco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de encntrar la solución [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag).

lo he cambiado a:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static "" as baseUrl %}

<img class="avatar border-gray" src="{{baseUrl}}img/avatars/{{request.user.avatar}}">
```